# Java3D Zoon- Object starts disppearing az I zoom on it

Tags: zooming, java-3d

First of all, I would like to say that I'm a newbie in Java3D. Please bear with my ignorance.
 I have made an application with Java3D and I have the following problems with zooming.

1. It seems the MouseWheelZoom behaviour of Java3D moves the object along Z-axis. On the scene my Z-axis is not out of plane so by using MouseWheelZoom , the object doesn't get closer but it get out of screen. Is there a way to set the zoom direction to an arbitrary direction?
2. I have got around the problem by using MouseWheelListener and changing the viewing platform based on zoom steps. But there is another problem now.  As the object gets closer than a certain distance, some parts of the object ( usually the corners) start disappearing so I can't zoom as much as I desire.

Could you please help ?

Regards,

Hassan

Answer (score 0):

1. Question:
   I guess you use an OrbitBehavior for MouseControl like:

   ```
   orbit = new OrbitBehavior(canvas3d, OrbitBehavior.REVERSE_ALL);
   ```

If that is the case then try

```
    orbit.setZoomFactor(-1d);
```

To reverse the zoom direction (the default zoom factor is +1d).

To your 2. Question:
You have to set a BoundingLeaf on your PlatformGeometry to encapsulate your "viewing area".
Try something like this

```
defaultBounds = new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(radiusGameMap, 0.0, radiusGameMap),
            radiusGameMap * 6.0d);
BoundingLeaf boundingLeaf = new BoundingLeaf(defaultBounds);
PlatformGeometry platformGeom = new PlatformGeometry();
platformGeom.addChild(boundingLeaf);
```

where radiusGameMap is a double defining the radius of your whole map.